# How can I get the meta out of this array in a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, post, meta

I have another (may stupid) question:

How can I get the "Olaf" (or everything else what is there) from the meta in this array in a $variable ?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Pagekit\Blog\Model\Post Object (
        [id]    => 1
        DateTimeObject (
            [bla]   => Bla
        )
        Pagekit\User\Model\User Object (
            [bla]   => bla
        )
        [meta] => Array ( 
            [og:description] => Olaf 
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried this? $variable = $arr[0]["meta"]["og:description"];

Comment: @Fabio I tried, but it doesn't work, I made it like this: 
    $test = patition($posts, 3);
    $var1 = $test[0]["meta"]["og:description"];
the patition function divides only the whole array in 3 parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `meta` is a key under object of `[0]th` key of main array. You should be able to get the values using `->`.

```
$var1 = $test[0]->meta["og:description"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$meta_desc = $arr[0]->meta['og:description']
```

I understand that first element of array is an object.